# How to show Interstitial ads after x seconds on app

Tags: android, mobile, admob, interstitial

I set an insterstitital add that shows inmediatelly when the app is opened but I would like it to appear lets say after a minute.

Here is the part of my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");


AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Bind to the service
    try {
        bindIntent = new Intent(this, RadioService.class);
        bindService(bindIntent, radioConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telephonyManager != null) {
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    handler = new Handler();
    initialize();

    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
}
public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

Help is welcome!!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a Handler for that:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();


     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
      displayInterstitial();
                }
            },60000);

   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
```

Here 60000 is time in ms

so if you need for 20 mins then 60000*20

Comment: Could you tell me to where should it set exactly? I tried in two parts of the code but it still appears inmediately after start. :(

Comment: write anywhere after loadad also ad is displaying after because you havent removed the    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    }); code, remove it

Comment: Now yes! Thank you very much Cold Fire!  In this case the ad will appear once after 1 minute and never show again. In case I want to repeat for example after 20 minutes can I specify in the same handler? What I see in this example is that app starts, ad appears after 1 minute. Thanks ok. When I hit home to do something and I return to the app, after a minute the ad appears again. Is that normal?

Comment: in case if you want to repeat for 20 mins change the time of handler for 20 mins

Comment: Thanks! I´ll give a try! by the way, this is ok for admob policy? as the ad is not shown inmediatelly after app starts, but 1 minute after its opened. I read that inmediatelly is not allowed, so that´s why I want to set it after 1 or 5 minutes after.

Comment: Both methods are a violation of Admob policy. Don't do this. Instead show your add at a natural break point in your app. If your app doesn't have a natural breakpoint then it is not a good candidate for interstitial ads.